# javascript date with string

Tags: javascript, date, formatting

I'm trying to convert a date in javascript from MM/dd/yyyy to yyyy/MM/dd

so this **works**:

```
var d = new Date("08/08/2012");
dateString = d.getFullYear() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getDate();
document.write(dateString);
```

output = 2012/7/8

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

this does **not**:

```
var dateString = "08/08/2012";
var d = new Date(dateString);
dateString = d.getFullYear() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getDate();
document.write(dateString);
```

and **neither does this**:

```
var dateString = "08/08/2012";
var d = Date.parse(dateString);
dateString = d.getFullYear() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getDate();
document.write(dateString);
```

how do I make it work with a string variable? thanks

~Myy

Comment: What does the browser's console log when it tries to execute the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Are you saying that you *want* 08/08/2012 to print as 2012/7/8 (i.e., with the month changed from 08 to 7)?

Comment: no, I was having a problem using a string variable vs the new Date() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var dateString = "08/08/2012";
var d = new Date(dateString);
dateString = d.getFullYear() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getDate();
document.write(dateString);
```

That should, [and does](http://jsfiddle.net/ZscEC/), work.  Keep in mind that JavaScript stores months as a zero-indexed value.

If you want to have leading zeros, then you'll have to do some magic:

```
var dateString = "08/08/2012";
var d = new Date(dateString);
dateString = d.getFullYear() + "/" + ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
document.write(dateString);​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkqmH/)

The reason why your `Date.parse( )` example is not working, is because that function returns a timestamp (number of milliseconds since 1970), instead of a Date object.  Therefore, you can't call functions like `getFullYear()` on the timestamp.

Comment: The million dollar question is why `Date.parse` doesn't work.

Comment: @Nick `Date.parse` does work, but it doesn't return a Date object.  It returns a timestamp.

Comment: I swear I tried the second method time after time, and it didn't work, and now that I tried again it worked. I guess I was missing something, Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @MrSlayer I really wish they would have named the function better.

Answer (score 4):

If all you need to do is re-order the values, you can do:

```
var dateString = "08/08/2012";
var dateElements = dateString.split("/");
var outputDateString = dateElements[2] + "/" + dateElements[0] + "/" + dateElements[1];
document.write(outputDateString );
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm with MrSlayer that the code works in jsFiddle.

Your attempts at using `Date.parse()` should actuall be using `Date(String(dateString))`.

Don't forget to add 1 for each month.